# Webstorm Debugging NPM Script Through IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm

Trying to debug an NPM script from within Webstorm. The application runs through the NPM scripts, but when debugging the script it always crashes. I know that there is the flag `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION`, but adding that doesn't seem to work.

Script:

```
"dev": "npm run dev:server & npm run build:client:watch",
"dev:server": "npm run build:server:watch & nodemon --harmony lib/server",
"build:client:watch": "WEBPACK_DEV=true NODE_ENV=development STACK=local node lib/server/webpack",
"build:server:watch": "npm run transpile:watch -- -d lib/common src/common & npm run transpile:watch -- -d lib/server src/server",
"transpile": "BABEL_ENV=node babel",
"transpile:watch": "npm run transpile -- --watch",
```

According to Webstorm: `To debug the "dev" script, make sure the $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION string is specified as the first argument for the node command you'd like to debug. For example: { "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js" }`

But even when adding this in different places it will still give me an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone reading this in 2020, you just need to right-click the script in the NPM panel and select "Debug ".

You can then set breakpoints in the script and debug in the Debug panel panes, Debugger, Console, etc..

To re-run the script, click the bug icon in the Debug panel.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using node8, where this will not work because in node 8 V8 debugger API had been superseded by the V8 inspector API. For more info look at this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13564), In previous versions of nodejs this works. For node 8 you should check the WebStorm site, they have information about how to work with the new inspector protocol https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html?search=node

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did read that and did research but I am running v6.11.0 so it doesn't apply to me

Comment: @Jmrapp I didn't noticed at first that you have write differently this Const NODE_DEBUG_OPTION, I always used this %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% just like Webstorm informs me,  and it works on nodejs 6 , what Webstorm version are you using?  And what error exactly you get?

Comment: I am running on a Mac, not windows, and doing research it seems that the windows version of the const is % NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% and the mac version is $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION. Webstorm specifically tells me to use $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION whenever debugging the application

Comment: @Jmrapp, ok I understand, and what error you get, and Webstorm version are you using?